# Make does not find a command

Tags: makefile

in my makefile i use a programm called mid2gba so i included the directory to my path variable. Launching the programm from the shell works just fine (if i type mid2gba [opts] [input]).
However when i try to use the programm in my makefile it always tells me:

```
/bin/sh: mid2agb: command not found
```

I defined the call by using:

```
MID2AGB=@mid2agb
```

And the rule in which i call mid2abg is:

```
$(MIDAS): $(BLDPATH)/%.s: %.mid
    $(shell mkdir -p $(dir $@))
    $(MID2AGB) $(MIDFLAGS) $< $@
```

Edit:

What i would like to add: mid2agb is not located in bin/sh and also when i replace the mid2gba in the Variable with the entire path everything just works fine

Comment: Why are you using `$(shell mkdir -p ...)` instead of just writing `mkdir -p ...`?  Anyway, there's not enough information here to know why this is not working.  Make doesn't modify the `PATH` environment variable on its own, so there's something about your setup which is not right but you haven't shown us enough to know what it is.  My suspicion is that you've set the `PATH` variable in your makefile to something else.

Comment: Using `@` and then asking us to debug in the blind is counter-productive.  What happens if you take out the `@` in `@mid2agb`?

Comment: Your code says `mid2agb` while everything else says `mid2gba`. Could it be so simple as a typo in the command name?

Comment: Ok, sorry for posting this problem, simpley restarting my pc did the job...